# How can I access the number of errors that my App Engine app is returning per hour/day/week?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

Is there an API that my Google App Engine app can call when signed in as the as the app admin that would return information on the number of errors (404, 500, etc.) my app is returning?

I'd like to setup a simple cron job in my application to count the number of errors that my app is returning every few minutes and send me an email if the error rate becomes unexpectedly high. I'd like to avoid having to scrape the information from the Appspot dashboard or run another process outside of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you need is probably [LogService API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logservice/functions)

Note that it isn't available for Java runtime (yet, I assume).

Comment: Yes. I went with something like: logservice.fetch(minimum_log_level=logservice.LOG_LEVEL_ERROR).count()

Comment: If that number is high, you're going to run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

This only works on the **cloud** and is GAE-friendly.

You will need jsoup.

```
package some.package


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Method;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AppEngineScraperUtil
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( AppEngineScraperUtil.class );

    /**
     * @param appId
     *            in the form of {@code appId}
     * @return dashboard in html
     */
    public static String fetchDashboard( String appId )
    {
        return jsoupWay( appId );
    }

    private static String jsoupWay( String appId )
    {
        try
        {
            Connection conn = createGetConn( "https://appengine.google.com" );
            Response result = conn.execute();
            Document doc = result.parse();
            // parse inputs
            Elements elements = doc.select( "#dsh, [name=GALX], #service, #continue, #ltmpl" );
            Map<String, String> formFields = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // build form
            for ( Element element: elements )
                formFields.put( element.attr( "name" ), element.val() );
            formFields.put( "Email", "xxx" );
            formFields.put( "Passwd", "xxx" );
            String formAction = doc.select( "form" ).first().attr( "action" );
            // parse cookies
            Map<String, String> cookies = result.cookies();
            // build post
            conn = createPostConn( formAction );
            conn.cookies( cookies );
            conn.data( formFields );
            conn.header( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            result = conn.execute();
            doc = result.parse();
            // get dashboard
            conn = createGetConn( "https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=" + appId );
            conn.cookies( result.cookies() );
            result = conn.execute();
            // return html
            doc = result.parse();
            return doc.toString();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            logger.error( "Error retrieving dashboard.", e );
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Connection createPostConn( String url )
    {
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect( url );
        conn.method( Method.POST );
        return conn;
    }

    private static Connection createGetConn( String url )
    {
        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect( url );
        conn.method( Method.GET );
        return conn;
    }
}
```